# undefined method `name' for "aaronh-chronic":String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

### Im getting this error on bundle install

- undefined method `name' for "aaronh-chronic":String (NoMethodError)

rail version 2.3.14

Comment: I'm not getting this error.

Comment: Did you forget to put aaronh-chronic in quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to gem problem,

Try this

gem update --system 1.6.2